# Cannot connect postgreSQL server to pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I know there are a lot of similar questions on this site, but so far I've been unable to find any answers. I have a postgres 13 server running on a WSL distro, ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to connect a gui to the server. I've tried Postbird and pgAdmin 4, both give me a similar error:

'Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?'

Steps I have tried:

- I can connect to the server inside of ubuntu by running psql.
- I have changed the postgresql.conf file to include listen_addresses = '*'
- I have modified the pg_hba.conf file to look like:
  [pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYsIB.png)
- I have confirmed that the server is indeed running on port 5432.

Thanks for reading. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pgAdmin is running in the Windows host? At a guess you have to find what IP the WSL distro is listening on. From the looks of it that is not `localhost`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your reply! pgAdmin is running on the windows host. Could you elaborate on what you mean? I used `netstat -ano | findstr 5432` in cmd to check if the server was running there, and indeed it was.

Comment: The `5432` is not the problem it is the IP address/interface the Postgres server in the WSL guest is listening on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So my issue was indeed the pg_hba.conf file. I had to add a line at the bottom

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust`

Once I did that, I restarted my server and was able to connect.