# cannot connect postgresql running on localhost to pgadmin

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

i simply cannot connect pgadmin to the postgresql running on local host!

i followed the official [Ubuntu document](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-postgresql) for setting postgres up. i can also access the db through terminal easily by using:
`psql --host localhost --username <user_name> --password -p 5433 --dbname <db_name>` 
the error generated by the pgadmin interface is this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQBxz.png)

while the above mentioned command in terminal executes successfully and outputs:

```
psql (14.9 (Ubuntu 14.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

iam using ubuntu :
`Linux d 5.19.0-50-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 10 18:24:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
and psql --version is :
`psql (PostgreSQL) 14.9 (Ubuntu 14.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)`

content of postgresql.conf is as follows:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/14/main'      
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf'    
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_ident.conf'    
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pid'           
listen_addresses = '*'      
port = 5433             
max_connections = 100           
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' 
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
shared_buffers = 128MB          
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] %q%u@%d '        
cluster_name = '14/main'            
stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'         
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
include_dir = 'conf.d'
```

i also tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277286/cannot-connect-postgresql-server-to-pgadmin-4) solution  but it didn't work, beside,this is not really a safe way to achieve it!

Comment: try localhost instead of the ip

Comment: Similar question at serverfault: [cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-local-machine-using-ip-pgadmin](https://serverfault.com/questions/443153/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-local-machine-using-ip-pgadmin) I wouldn't say its "not safe" to allow connections from ip addresses. You don't have to allow all connections - just the ones that need access. psql isn't using http to connect, that's why its working. PgAdmin does use http, so postgres needs to be configured to allow http connections.

Comment: @nbk i did. unfortunately nothing changed !;(

Comment: @topsail i did the thing you mentioned, still no luck, i really have no idea what else to try!

Comment: Its a little odd I guess. When you say you are running pgadmin locally - is everything local? Like you are working on your own projects (school/personal/hobby) where everything is local and there are no outside connections? Or is this a production setup or something at work? What is the contents of your `postgresql.conf` file?

Comment: do you really have a user `root` is that a user you created?

Comment: @topsail yes, that's a user created with createdb and superuser access

Comment: Lots more things to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432